# asyncio with synchronous code

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a module which makes blocking network requests to some TCP server and receive responses. I must integrate it into asyncio application. My module looks like this:

```
import socket

# class providing transport facilities
# can be implemented in any manner
# for example it can manage asyncio connection
class CustomTransport:
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.host = host
        self.port = port

    def write(self, data):
        left = len(data)
        while left:
            written = self.sock.send(data.encode('utf-8'))
            left = left - written
            data = data[written:]

    def read(self, sz):
        return self.sock.recv(sz)

    def open(self):
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))

    def close(self):
        self.sock.shutdown(2)


# generated. shouldn't be modified
# however any transport can be passed
class HelloNetClient:
    def __init__(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport

    def say_hello_net(self):
        self.transport.write('hello')
        response = self.transport.read(5)
        return response


# can be modified
class HelloService:
    def __init__(self):
        # create transport for connection to echo TCP server
        self.transport = CustomTransport('127.0.0.1', 6789)
        self.hello_client = HelloNetClient(self.transport)

    def say_hello(self):
        print('Saying hello...')
        return self.hello_client.say_hello_net()

    def __enter__(self):
        self.transport.open()
        return self

    def __exit__(self,exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.transport.close()
```

Usage:

```
def start_conversation():
    with HelloService() as hs:
        answer = hs.say_hello()
        print(answer.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_conversation()
```

Now I see that only way to turn my module to be compatible with ***asyncio*** is to convert everything to coroutines and replace regular socket with asyncio-provided transport. But I don't want to touch generated code (HelloNetClient). Is it possible?

P.S. I want it to be used like this:

```
async def start_conversation():
    async with HelloService() as hs:
        answer = await hs.say_hello()
        print(answer.decode('utf-8'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(start_conversation())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HelloService` will probably need to use `run_in_executor` (which manages a thread pool) to run `HelloNetClient` methods in the background. For example:

```
async def say_hello(self):
    print('Saying hello...')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    return await loop.run_in_executor(None, self.hello_client.say_hello_net)
```

This is not an idiomatic use of asyncio, and you're missing out on some of its features - for example, you won't be able to create thousands of clients that all work in parallel, and you won't get reliable cancellation (ability to `cancel()` any task you wish). Nonetheless, simple usage will work just fine.

Unfortunately the ability to provide custom transports is not of help here because the middle tier, `HelloNetClient`, expects synchronous behavior. Even if you were to write a custom transport that hooked into asyncio, methods like `say_hello_net` would still wait for as long as it takes for the response to arrive, so `HelloService` would have to schedule them in a separate thread. For this reason your best bet is to use the default transport and connect the code with asyncio with the code in the service as shown above.

Comment: **This is not an idiomatic use of asyncio** - most important part.  So in a real world scenario I would need to call DB & other APIs.. so is it better to actually use Async DB drivers + async http clients? or can we live with async http clients and thread pooled DB calls?

Comment: @bhathiya-perera If you have async libraries, you should definitely use them. `run_in_executor` is just a helper for executing legacy sync code in an async context.